# decompress a .z file in java

Tags: java, gzip, 7zip, compression

I am trying to decompress .z file from java on a 64-bit windows machine. This compressed file contains folders and files. How do i do this?

I have tried the following:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("uncompress", zFilePath);
Process p = pb.start();
```

But i get this:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "uncompress": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
```

Please advise,

thanks!

Comment: the answer posted on the other thread did not work for me. I am getting a null pointer exception:  at sqlfinder.UnZip$1.write(UnZip.java:48)
 at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.impl.InArchiveImpl.nativeExtract(Native Method)
 at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.impl.InArchiveImpl.extractSlow(InArchiveImpl.java:107)
 at net.sf.sevenzipjbinding.simple.impl.SimpleInArchiveItemImpl.extractSlow(SimpleInArchiveItemImpl.java:190)
 at sqlfinder.UnZip.main(UnZip.java:41)

Comment: `.z` is the good old Unix compress format - this is different from 7z.

Comment: I wish I could write a full answer.  `CreateProcess error=2` is "file not found" so `uncompress` is either not installed or not on your `PATH`.  Apache Commons Compress provides a pure Java alternative - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/

Comment: Thanks Stepfan!!! I will take a look at the Apache project